# Get clicked item ID in posted data on clicking item command in repeater using ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, post, dynamic-controls, asprepeater, itemcommand

I want to get the ID of the Command-button on repeater that has been clicked in posted data on a server when it has been click.

When I check the posted data it is something like this:

> ctl00$ctl00$MainContentPlaceHolder$MainContentPlaceHolder$lvEstates$ctl00$MainContentPlaceHolder_MainContentPlaceHolder_lvEstates_ctl00_colEdit_cmd.x
>   = 7 ctl00$ctl00$MainContentPlaceHolder$MainContentPlaceHolder$lvEstates$ctl00$MainContentPlaceHolder_MainContentPlaceHolder_lvEstates_ctl00_colEdit_cmd.y=9

Why does it show in X and Y? How can I find which item was clicked?

It was the first item in repeater and the column was 15 (zero based).

Comment: The ID is generated by the place the control has/gets in the control-hierarchy when the page is build; meaning you'll see something like that. You shouldn't put logic in the naming of a control because when you change the page structure, the ID can change. Instead I would use the Command Name and/or the Command Argument on the control and read that out from your OnItemCommand on your Repeaters postback function.

Comment: thank you for your reply for some reason i want to catch it on init and get the id of clicked command so is there any way to find out the id with this information?!

Comment: You should be able to find it in the Request.Form collection, and then parse it from there.

Comment: it's exactly what's in Request.Form collection